# Add input search and do a ajax call, nothing displayed

Tags: reactjs

I started to develop with reactjs.

Actually, when page is display, data coming from an ajax call are show.

```
var WebSite = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {display: true };
  },
  render: function() {

    if (this.state.display==false) return null;
    else return (
      <tr>
          <td>{this.props.website.webSite}</td>
          <td>{this.props.website.date}</td>
          <td>{this.props.website.visits}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
});

var WebSiteTable = React.createClass({

  render: function() {

    var rows = [];
    this.props.websites.forEach(function(website) {
      rows.push(
        <WebSite website={website} key={website.website} />);
    });

    return (
      <table className="table table-striped">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>Website</th>
                  <th>Date</th>
                  <th>Visits</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
});

var App = React.createClass({

  searchWebSiteFromDate: function() {

    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/rest/report/statwebsiteg",
      }).then(function(data) {
        self.setState({ websites: data});
      });

  },

  getInitialState: function() {
    return { websites: [] };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.searchWebSiteFromDate();
  },

  render() {
    return ( <WebSiteTable websites={this.state.websites} /> );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root') );
```

That work fine, instead of display data directly when page is loading, i would like to display an input box. On the lost focus, i would like to do a similar search then the current one (adding input box) and displaying result.

I changed App with this code

```
var App = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function () {
        return {websites: []};
    },

    onBlur: function () {
        var self = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8080/rest/report/statwebsiteg",
        }).then(function (data) {
            self.setState({websites: data});
        });
    },
    render: function () {

        return <input type="text" onBlur={ this.onBlur } placeholder="Enter your date here."/>;
    }

});
```

Query is done... but nothing is displayed.

Comment: I assume you have the website table component along with input in the App component. Did you tried logging the value? It will be much better to help if you add the exact code of what you tried..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your example is incomplete, you won't see the data unless you actually render it.

```
render: function () {
    return (
        <section>
            <input type="text" onBlur={ this.onBlur } placeholder="Enter your date here."/>
            <WebSiteTable websites={this.state.websites} />
        </section>

    );
}
```